# How i can call SQL statement directly with magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, sql, query

how to call SQL statements directly to database with Magento 2, This is not recommended, but in some situation we need to do this, for some very special tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that this can be done properly:

```
class CallSQLStatement extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $resource;
    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resource = $resource;
   }

   public function getSkus($baseSku) 
   {
       $connection = $this->resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
       $catalogProduct = $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity');
    
       $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT sku FROM `".$catalogProduct."` WHERE sku like '".$baseSku."%'");
       var_dump(result);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Running SQL statements directly to database is not recommended but in some case we can use like:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('Your Table Name');/****** Your table name******/ 

//Select All Data Present in Table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;

$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); /****** Return Array with values******/

//Delete Data from table

$sql = "Delete FROM " . $tableName." Where emp_id = 10";

$connection->query($sql);

//Insert Data into table

$sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (column1, column2, column3, 
column4) Values ('','XYZ','ABD20','50000')";

$connection->query($sql);

//Update Data into table

$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set column1 = xyz where column2 = xyz";

$connection->query($sql);
```